# Determining the measurable space and density function for an event

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have 10 balls. 3 of the balls are faulty. I choose 5 balls without returning them back to the stack of balls.

$X$ $=$ "the amount of faulty balls"

- Is the measurable space of this scenario (10, 2) or something entirely different?
- How can I build a probability density function for $X$?

Comment: $X$ is a discrete random variable taking integer values, so has a probability mass function rather than a probability density

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A:=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$.

You can take $\Omega=\{\omega\in\wp(A)\mid |\omega|=5\}$ as sample space and $\wp(\Omega)$ as $\sigma$-algebra.

$\Omega$ has $\binom{10}5$ elements and the events $\{\omega\}\in\wp(\Omega)$ are equiprobable, so that $P(\{\omega\})=\binom{10}5^{-1}$ for each $\omega\in\Omega$.

This determines $P$ so now [probability space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space) $(\Omega,\wp(\Omega),P)$ is constructed.

Now let's say that the balls corresponding with the numbers $1,2$ and $3$ are faulty.

Then random variable $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ is prescribed by: $$\omega\mapsto|\omega\cap\{1,2,3\}|$$

Evidently $X$ takes values in $\{0,1,2,3\}$ and you can find the probability *mass* function (not density) of $X$ by finding the $p_X(k):=P(X=k)$ for $k=0,1,2,3$.

Comment: So the end result of me having a probability mass function would be a function with the variable $k={0,1,2,3}$ and $f(k)$ would be the probability of having k faulty balls when doing the act?

Comment: Yes. You can also look at is a function on the set of nonnegative integers that only takes positive values on $0,1,2,3$ and takes value $0$ on the others.

Comment: I came up with $P(X=k) = \frac{\frac{7!}{5-k}\frac{3!}{k}}{\frac{10!}{5!}}$, and I'm guessing it's legit since it adds up to $1$ with all $0..3$ $k$ values

Comment: It is hypergeometric distribution and $P(X=k)=\frac{\binom3k\binom7{5-k}}{\binom{10}5}$.