# Random variable - strange definition and example

Tags: probability, statistics

My book said that a random variable $X(\omega)$ is a function which maps each outcome $\omega$ of the sample space on a real number and the set of the outcomes which verify the inequality:

$$ \left\lbrace X(\omega) \leq a \right\rbrace $$

with $a$ real parameter, have to be an event for all value of $a$.

What does the above inequality mean? Can you explain it with an example please?

Thank you for your willingness.

Comment: For an example see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2619091/75923) where a probability space is constructed in order to model a situation in which probabilities must be found. I would not call $a\in\mathbb R$ a parameter but a constant.

Comment: My teacher used to tell me that a random variable is not a random and it is also not a variable but still its a random variable. I hope now you know what $a$ is

Comment: In short, it is telling you that $X$ is measurable wrt to a certain sigma algebra (known as borel sigma algebra). But if you don't know what these things are (and have not been properly introduced by the book) then it can be very confusing. I'd suggest reading the definition of random variable from scratch on wikipedia or on a nicer book :-)

Comment: Hello @Ant51, my book doesn not introduce sigma-algebra, maybe it is better if I use another definition.

Comment: Actually the correct notation is **not** $\{X(\omega)\leq a\}$ but it is $\{X\leq a\}$ which on is an abbreviation of the set $\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X(\omega)\leq a\}$. As long as $\sigma$-algebras are not introduced you can assume that **every** subset of $\Omega$ is an *event* (hence has a probability to occur).

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi You can look up on wikipedia. If you want a book, I'd reccomend *Probability Essential*, Jacod, Protter. It's very short, very brief, very accurate.

Comment: @drhab thank you for your revision

Comment: @Ant Good book!

Comment: I'd advise you to get started with discrete stochastics (i.e. stochastics with discrete random variables) first. It's somewhat clearer what and why you do stuff, and should ease your understanding. Once you've got that down, you can move on to continuous random variables, and it'll be a lot easier